# Toggle animation not work

Tags: jquery

Hi all i have this script and I want when I click `#select` tag height should be 200px and when I click next time get back 20px

```
$('#select').click(function(){
        $('#select').toggle(
            function(){
                $('#select').animate({height:"200px"},200);
            },
             function(){
                $('#select').animate({height:"20px"},200);
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `toggle` event method doesn't exist in latest versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The `toggle()` method doesn't really work that way, inside a `click()` function. Consider simplifying your script and using CSS transitions:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7gk7mvzv

```
#select {
    background: #eee;
    height: 50px;
}
#select.height20 {
    height: 20px;
    transition: height 0.2s;
}
#select.height200 {
    height: 200px;
    transition: height 0.2s;
}

$('#select').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('height20 height200')
});

<div id="select" class="height20">Select div</div>
```